# Excel random number keep recalculating

Tags: excel, random, numbers

This is my function :

```
=NORMINV(RAND(),$A$1,$A$2)
```

When I do something other, the random number recalculate again

How can I make the random number static on the 1st

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the RAND() function is meant to work in Excel. If you want a static number, you can just paste its value ;)

However, if you are open to using VBA, you can do it by performing manual calculations with your uncalculated cell in A1 for example :

```
sub refreshRand()
  range ("A1").formula = "=NORMINV(RAND(),$A$1,$A$2)"
  range ("A1").calculate
  range ("A1").value = range ("A1").value
end sub
```

Note: If you finished your work and want to stop all calculations on ALL cells in the sheet, you can set it in Excel Settings -> Manual Calculation

Comment: Any other function than RAND() can make static random number?

Comment: Not in Excel. But it can be easily done with VBA, are you familiar with coding in VBA? See this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011032/compute-a-static-random-number-compute-it-once-in-excel

Comment: Not really, but my random number is generated based on mean and standard deviation

Comment: In this case, use the first solutio, which is to hardcode the cell's value by pasting its value into the cell. You can always keep the cell with the formula next to it in case you want to regenerate a new random number ( you would just paste it again). That's all I can do for you, good luck!

Comment: I right click work sheet then > view code and i paste ur coding but it doest work