Excel RAND() static
Using excel to get a random sample of rows for quality assurance purposes.
Currently using the RAND() function in a column and then have a filter selecting those columns under 0.10 to be part of the sample. However, as the RAND() function is volatile it refreshes each time a change is made on the spreadsheet.
Currently I am copying and pasting as values to bypass this issue, but it is quite manual across several spreadsheets and would like to automate it.
Due to constraints I cannot turn off calculations or use macros. Has anyone found any workarounds or solutions to this issue?

What about a short script in vba to do the copy paste special?

You've already found the workarounds and solutions, you've just said you can't use them. I only know of 2 "static formulas" ctrl+; and ctrl+: Might be a better approach to explore why you can't turn off calculations or use macros - and find a workaround for that.

This could be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333708/16578424

Write your own rnd? don't see why you can't implement this for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift since you have bitshift and xor functions in Excel.

Have looked at answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011032/compute-a-static-random-number-compute-it-once-in-excel but I don't see how they answer OP's question because they either use VBA, manual copy/paste or circular references

I will add another answer to the original question
