# getting a unique number for the contents of a cell

Tags: excel, hash, case, case-sensitive

I am looking for a HASH or maybe something even simpler.

I want to return a unique number for every string in a cell.

Does anyone know if there is a function in a cell that will return a unique number or a unique string for another string?

The problem is I would like to compare whether two string are totally equal, I need to be case sensitive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to compare 2 strings in a case sensitive way ignoring the Option Compare setting use StrComp
 IF StrComp(Str1,Str2,vbBinaryCompare)=0 then

Answer (score -1):

If you're in C# then can't you just use the standard `GetHash` function when you have a string variable that contains the contents of the cell?

Otherwise the following stack overflow question seems to already answer this question: [Password hash function for Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125785/password-hash-function-for-excel-vba)

Comment: I thought this was a reasonable answer. Could the "down-voter" let me know why I got the down vote?