# MD5 Hash function in excel without using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, md5

I need a function that will take an entire cell value in Excel and convert the value into its MD5 hash equivalent in a new cell.

Is there a formula in excel that does that? I need a solution that doesn't use VBA. Is this possible?

Comment: *"I need solution without using VBA."* Short answer to this: No.

Comment: A VBA approach is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125785/password-hash-function-for-excel-vba/125844.  You don't say why your requirements prohibit VBA, and I'm not sure there's a non-VBA solution.

Comment: @user2002935 pure Excel formulas solution is hardly ever possible, and I don't think it's worth the efforts. Look towards VBA and provide your ideas / initial code for community assistance.

Comment: Everything is possible, you can implement the whole algorithm in multi hidden sheets, then request the user to key the entry in particular cell and retrieve the hash from another cell. The question is, do you really wanna do it this way?

Comment: What is the data range for the cell values?
Is it something you can predict with a given pattern?
Like a string sequence?

Comment: I could write that for you for a low price.

Comment: I would love to see that done in pure Excel.

Comment: Here is a good past question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717526/vba-hash-string/14749855

Comment: I made a demo where the excel file consumes a webservice that generate the md5sum for a text (non vba at all). This link will expires in 30 days. https://ufile.io/3olj5nps. Let me know if it will help you to post a proper answer

Answer (score 3):

Without VBA is possible to use webservice formula that invoke a webservice that return the md5sum.

**Explanation**

- *=WEBSERVICE(B4)*

  - Result: 89374b6dda3bb0e16132b21fb9887f1d
- *=CONCAT("https://md5sum.herokuapp.com/?text=";ENCODEURL(B3))*

  - Result: https://md5sum.herokuapp.com/?text=bruno%20tafarelo
- *B3* cells contains the text to be coded

  - Value: bruno tafarelo

[image: spreadsheet sample]

This web service was developed by me as all the services on internet require a POST method and Excel is only able to perform GET request. It's hosted in a free service and I don't know for how long it will be available.

Web service source code: https://github.com/btafarelo/md5sum

Answer (score 1):

This was actually answered (with a "Yes", it's possible, and here's the proof) but the answer has been mysteriously removed. Fortunately, the [Wayback Machine remembers the answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20201122092120/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201297/md5-hash-function-in-excel-without-using-vba). Basically, by using Excel's bitwise operations (`BITAND()`, `BITOR()`, `BITXOR()`, `BITR[L]SHIFT()`), an MD5 calculation can be made.

Somebody even [wrote a blog post](https://tzamtzis.gr/2017/web-analytics/excel-function-md5-hashing-without-vba/) on it, including [an example workbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20201122092120/https://tzamtzis.gr/tzamtziswp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/MD5.xlsx).