# How to implement hmac sha256 in VBA from scratch?

Tags: excel, cryptography, vba

For some reasons, I have to implement hmac sha256 in VBA from Scratch.

I've written the following code but I'm not getting the correct results (for verification, I'm using the following tables : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231#section-4.2)

Here is the code implemented :

In my code, the function Hash which corresponds to SHA256 is used from an external library and works fine (I could check the results). I assume then it's working properly but I'm quite sure the problem is coming from the conversion : Decimal, Hex, Byte... It's not something I master well.

I got the formulae from : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Can anyone help please with the following code. What's wrong with this HMAC implementation ?

Thank you in advance.

```
    Option Explicit
     
    Public Sub Main()
        'Key declaration
        Dim Key As String
        Dim KeyBytes() As Byte
        
        'Message declaration
        Dim Message As String
        Dim MessageBytes() As Byte
        
        'ipad, opad
        Dim iPad_() As Byte
        Dim oPad_() As Byte
        
        'Size
        Dim n As Long

        'Output
        Dim Result() As Byte
        Dim A() As Byte, B() As Byte
        
        n = 64
           
        'Define the key
        Key = "123"
        KeyBytes = Key  'Convert string to byte
        KeyBytes = CompleteKey(KeyBytes, n) 'At this step there are 64 Bytes in the key
        
        'Define the message
        Message = "TestMessage"
        MessageBytes = Message  'Convert string to byte
        
        'Define ipad, opad
        iPad_ = ipad(n)
        oPad_ = opad(n)
            
        'Get the XOR operation of the key and ipad
        B = XOR_(KeyBytes, iPad_)
        
        'Concatenate the result with the message
        B = Concatenate(B, MessageBytes)
        
        'Compute the final hash
        A = XOR_(KeyBytes, oPad_)
        Result = Hash(Concatenate(A, Hash(B)))
    End Sub

    Public Function CompleteKey(KeyBytes() As Byte, n As Long) As Byte()
        Dim O() As Byte
        
        If UBound(KeyBytes) < n Then
            O = KeyBytes
            ReDim Preserve O(n - 1)
        End If
               
        CompleteKey = O
    End Function
     
    Public Function XOR_(Item1() As Byte, Item2() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        Dim A As String, B As String
        Dim Output()  As Byte
        
        ReDim Output(UBound(Item2) - 1)
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(Item1) - 1
            A = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(Item1(i), 8)
            B = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(Item2(i), 8)
            Output(i) = WorksheetFunction.Bin2Dec(XorBinary(A, B))
        Next i
                                       
        For j = i To UBound(Item2) - 1
            Output(i) = Item2(j)
        Next j
     
        XOR_ = Output
    End Function
     
    Public Function XorBinary(x As String, y As String) As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim n As Long
        Dim A As Long
        Dim B As Long
        Dim C As String
        Dim O As String
       
        n = Len(x)
       
        For i = 1 To n
            A = CLng(Right(Left(x, i), 1))
            B = CLng(Right(Left(y, i), 1))
           
            If A * B = 0 And A + B = 1 Then
                C = "1"
            Else
                C = "0"
            End If
           
            O = O & C
        Next i
    End Function
     
     
    Public Function ipad(n As Long) As Byte()
        Dim S() As Byte
        Dim i As Long
          
        ReDim S(n)
            
        For i = 1 To n
            S(i) = 36
        Next i
       
        ipad = S
    End Function
     
    Public Function opad(n As Long) As Byte()
        Dim S() As Byte
        Dim i As Long
          
        ReDim S(n)
            
        For i = 1 To n
            S(i) = 92   '5C
        Next i
       
        opad = S
    End Function

    Public Function Concatenate(A() As Byte, B() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim C() As Byte
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        
        ReDim C(UBound(A) + UBound(B) + 1)
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(A)
            C(i) = A(i)
        Next i
        
        For j = i To i + UBound(B) - 1
            C(j) = B(j - UBound(A) - 1)
        Next j
        
        Concatenate = C
    End Function
```

Comment: Please ellaborate what "not getting the correct results" implies. Show us your input, output and desired output.

Comment: You will need to post, or link, the code for the `Hash` function otherwise how will people follow your steps ? Is it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel ?