# Excel formula-based function for SHA256 / SHA512 hashing without VBA or macros that will work for all rows in a column

Tags: excel, hash, sha256, sha512

I'm looking to use Excel to create hashes for all values in a column. Each row would contain the text to be hashed and it would put the hashed value/digest in the next column.

It would allow for other columns with other data that are not part of the hash.

This would be fully self-contained and not use VBA or macros.

[Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509572/excel-formula-based-function-for-sha256-sha512-hashing-without-vba-or-macros/56767828) I've found only work for a single value, or require Windows (vba). I'd prefer to find a solution that works on a Mac in case I need someone else to run the process I'm planning on using this for.

I also found a [Google solution](https://pthree.org/2016/02/26/digest-algorithms-in-google-spreadsheets/) but would prefer to keep this local and self-contained to simplify it for non-tech coworkers.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was the one who suggested you make a new post, I'll gave the unfortunate answer that, WITHOUT using VBA, this is not really possible (or at least not without an enormous amount of inefficient work).

Sorry, I didn't realize you wanted to maintain the no-vba restriction to calculate it. It's very easy to accomplish what you want using a VBA library and a custom function. [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel) gives great detail on how.

If you are desperate for something else (perhaps you want to use on web?), you could use Google Sheets. [Here's an example file I built](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alk5njX-ZK7jqWKqq9n9kGRmeXoP1O2dgWGYzbHf7fU/edit?usp=sharing).

Both outputs will give something like this:

[image]

Comment: I had found a google sheets solution and I suspect yours is using the same method but the script isn't viewable in your example. I linked to it above in my question.

Comment: @mindmischief yes, it is, you have to make your own copy of it in order to see it. Under Tools/Script Editor.