# HMAC SHA384 Function in VBA on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, hmac

Basically, on Excel, I do want to create a signature from a secret key and message using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) [SHA384](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sha384/).

I found some related articles but it was for HMAC SHA256

- [Porting SHA-256 library to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel): This works but I can't find any similar library for HMAC SHA384
- [Excel formula-based without VBA or Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509572/excel-formula-based-function-for-sha256-sha512-hashing-without-vba-or-macros/56767828#56767828): This works too, but again for SHA256
- [Excel VBA for HMAC SHA](https://daih73.hatenablog.jp/entry/20180726): This was Japanese but easy to understand, however, this solution seems for Windows with `CreateObject` using ActiveX that not support on Mac OS as I know.

And some other research but no luck till now.

So, is it possible to do the same for HMAC SHA384 on Excel Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is an answer, it is just the comments have too few characters.
This is an augmented comment.

I know very little about Mac Os development. I'm guessing that Mac Os has cryptography libraries just like windows, this might be it [SHA384 - Apple Developer Documentation - (Swift)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/sha384)  .

Then you'll need to code against that library, I'm guessing that will be in the Mac Os development language C++/Objective-C/Swift . Googling, [objective c sha384 "mac os" - Google Search](http://google.com/search?q=objective%20c%20sha384%20%22mac%20os%22) yields this as first match [Objective-C Hash Algorithms_ SHA-1, HAVAL, MD2, MD5, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512](http://example-code.com/objc/crypt_hash_algorithms.asp)

Next challenge is to take the C++/Objective-C/Swift code and call it from Excel VBA.  It seems on Mac Os the equivalent of a Windows Dll (Dynamic Link Library) is a dylib file.  And here is a Youtube video that does that, [How to build dylib for use in VBA within Excel for Mac OS - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBj_Uo-0y-Q)

I'm sorry I cannot give you a complete solution and also I apologise if some of the links do not match up (so the Apple link is for the Swift language and the YouTube video describes writing in C++).  I have never programmed on a Mac but I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer S Meaden, I really appreciate any help, even it's just an idea. I will try to do this way with a very single code first to see if it could work. If no one could provide other answers, I will vote the bounty for you. Thanks again!