# Calling Access function from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I'm trying to call the GUIDFromString Access function from Excel.

```
Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "DB.accdb")

MsgBox accessApp.GUIDFromString("PassingAString")

accessApp.Quit

Set accessApp = Nothing
```

I've tried different things but all generate an error.
The above is generating:

```
ActiveX component can't create object
```

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-guidfromstring-method-access)

EDIT: I just came across this post ([Password hash function for Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125785/password-hash-function-for-excel-vba)), using the code from Chris for my purposes.

Comment: Try `GUIDFromString` instead of `GUIDStromString` ...?

Comment: @Andre Whoops, corrected it. It generates a different error now "ActiveX component can't create object".

Comment: From your comments it seems more like you want a hash function.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125785/password-hash-function-for-excel-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I already found that post and edited my post including the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GUIDFromString` only works for actual GUID strings, it seems.

In Access:

```
? GUIDFromString("some string")
```

> ActiveX component can't create object

```
? References(1).Guid
{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

? GUIDFromString("{000204EF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
?  À  ?
```

It's a byte array, so Debug.Print or MsgBox don't really make sense, but with the GUID string the method works.

Comment: Thanks, in that case this function has no use for me :)