# How to apply Application.Match with values > 255 characters?

Tags: excel, vba

I loop through two sheets (OLD, NEW) to determine which values are non-existing in the other.
The values are not always in the same sequence, therefore I can't check row by row. I search to see if a value exists.

The following takes a long time to run. (01:50 min with my test ranges.)

```vb
Sub LOOPING()
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim StartTime As Double
StartTime = Timer
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim rngNEW As Range
Set rngNEW = Sheets("NEW").Range("D1:D6734")
Dim rngOLD As Range
Set rngOLD = Sheets("OLD").Range("D1:D6734")

a = ""
For Each item In rngNEW
    For Each item2 In rngOLD
        If item = item2 Then
            GoTo NextIter
        End If
    Next item2
    a = a & "," & item.Row
NextIter:
Next item

MsgBox a
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
MsgBox "RunTime : " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

The following runs fast but does not return anything (00:02 min with the same test ranges.)
I found the match function does not work with cell values greater than 255 characters. Some of the cell values exceed 3000 characters.

```vb
Sub MATCHING()
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim StartTime As Double
StartTime = Timer
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim rngNEW As Range
Set rngNEW = Sheets("NEW").Range("D1:D6734")
Dim rngOLD As Range
Set rngOLD = Sheets("OLD").Range("D1:D6734")

a = ""
For Each item In rngNEW
    If IsError(Application.Match(item, rngOLD, 0)) Then
        a = a & "," & item.Row
    End If
Next item
MsgBox a
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
MsgBox "RunTime : " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Is there a way to overcome the 255 character limit?

Comment: Did you try to fully qualify range references? Btw Could be helpful to avoid blank items, too.

Comment: The ranges are exact and there are no blank items in the range

Comment: So everything in New is in Old, not necessarily vice versa.

Comment: No, there may be more, less or different values in both NEW and OLD

Comment: Your code works for me as expected. What does "does not return anything" mean? `MsgBox a` is empty because `a` is `""`? What kind of data is in `D1:D6734`? Please show an excerpt.

Comment: Do you want to find OLD values not in NEW  also ? Are all the rows unique i.e no duplicates within the sheet.

Comment: Finding OLD values not in NEW would be even better still, but I can do without. As for duplicates on the same sheet, there are none.

Comment: @MK0111 I have update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the necessary dotNet components then this might work for you. It essentially hashes the text into a 40 byte string using [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and stores that as a dictionary key for the comparison between New and Old. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125785) for SHA1 subroutine.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LOOPING()
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim StartTime As Double
    StartTime = Timer
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Const COL = "D"
    Const LASTROW = 6734
    Dim wsNEW As Worksheet, wsOLD As Worksheet, wsDebug As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim key As String, msg As String, s As String
    Dim dictOLD As Object, dictNEW As Object

    With ThisWorkbook
       Set wsNEW = .Sheets("NEW")
       Set wsOLD = .Sheets("OLD")
       Set wsDebug = .Sheets("DEBUG")
    End With
    wsDebug.Cells.Clear
    wsDebug.Range("A1:D1") = Array("NEW Row", "NEW Value", "OLD Row", "OLD Value")
    n = 2

    ' build dictionary with SHA1 digests as keys
    Set dictOLD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To LASTROW
        key = Trim(wsOLD.Cells(i, COL))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            key = SHA1(key)
            dictOLD(key) = i
        End If
    Next

    ' scan NEW for items not in OLD
    msg = "NEW not in OLD:"
    Set dictNEW = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To LASTROW
        s = Trim(wsNEW.Cells(i, COL))
        If Len(s) > 0 Then
            key = SHA1(s)
            If Not dictOLD.exists(key) Then
                msg = msg & "," & i
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 1) = i
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 2) = s
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 3) = "No match"
                n = n + 1
            End If
            dictNEW(key) = i
        End If
    Next

   ' scan OLD for items not is NEW
    msg = msg & vbCr & "OLD not in NEW:"
    For i = 1 To LASTROW
        s = Trim(wsOLD.Cells(i, COL))
        If Len(s) > 0 Then
            key = SHA1(s)
            If Not dictNEW.exists(key) Then
                msg = msg & "," & i
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 1) = "No Match"
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 3) = i
                wsDebug.Cells(n, 4) = s
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "No Match"
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    MsgBox "RunTime : " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub

Public Function SHA1(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim Enc As Object, Prov As Object
    Dim Hash() As Byte, i As Integer

    Set Enc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set Prov = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider")

    Hash = Prov.ComputeHash_2(Enc.GetBytes_4(s))

    SHA1 = ""
    For i = LBound(Hash) To UBound(Hash)
        SHA1 = SHA1 & Hex(Hash(i) \ 16) & Hex(Hash(i) Mod 16)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You test `If IsError..`.

When there's no error, it just skips to the next iteration. This is why you are not getting anything. So you can change it to `If Not IsError(Application.Match(item, rngOLD,0)) Then`.

Also, you are timing this but you repeatedly concatenate to string `a` -- this is a well-known performance-killer (I quickly found [this article](https://www.nirsoft.net/vb/strclass.html) for an explanation) -- you improve on this by, for example, allocating each bit to a large array and then joining them all after you finish the loop

Comment: Removing  IsError returns an error `Run-time error 13, Type Mismatch`

Comment: `Application.Match` **returns** an error value, in opposite to `WorksheetFunction.Match` which **throws** error. So using  `IsError` is correct using `Application.Match`.

Comment: the logic is that `a` is to be updated if there is a match, when there is no error -- I'll modify my answer

Comment: @stifin Currently my code loops through rngNEW. for each value in rngNEW it checks is a similar value exists in rngOLD by means of `application.Match`. If it does not find a similar value in rngOLD it should give the row-number of the current line it is testing in rngNEW. The problem I am having is that it does not give me row numbers even if the exact same value does not exist in rngOLD.

Comment: Changing it into `If Not IsError(Application.Match(item, rngOLD,0)) Then` only gives me all the row numbers of values from rngNEW for which a similar value exists in rngOLD. (but also in this case it returns all row numbers eventhough the value is different)

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Most of the cell values have more than 255 characters.